# Trivial Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Can someone show me how to prove that the trivial metric space is indeed a metric space (if $a=b$ then $d(a,b)=0$ and if $a \ne b$ then $d(a,b)=1$)?

I'm having trouble with the triangle inequality property.

Comment: Don't vandalize your post, please. You are neither the first nor last person who has run into this issue. Leave it accessible for those who will come after.

Comment: Zev and AmWhy have already pointed out to you that you'll need to show $d(a,c)\leq d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ by cases. It's worth noting that there are ultimately only $2$ cases to consider--in particular: $a=c$, and $a\neq c$. In the first case, the inequality holds by nonnegativity of $d(a,b),d(b,c)$. In the second, at least one of $d(a,b),d(b,c)=1$, and the other is at least $0$, so again the inequality holds.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You want to prove that
$$d(a,c)\leq d(a,b)+d(b,c)$$
for all points $a,b,c$. For any given points $a,b,c$, just work through the possibilities:

- $a=b$ and $b=c$
- $a=b$ and $b\neq c$
- $a\neq b$ and $b=c$
- $a\neq b$ and $b\neq c$

What happens in each case?

Answer (score 3):

I trust you've covered the first two properties of the metric, which follow immediately from the definition of the trivial metric space:

- $d(a, b) \geq 0$ for all $a, b$
- $d(a, b) = 0 \iff a = b$ (by definition)

***Now, for proving triangle inequality holds:***

What are the possible cases for $d(a, b), d(b, c), d(a, c)$?

Either:

- $a = b, \; b = c,\;\implies a = c$;
- $a = b,\; b\neq c,\; \implies\; a \neq c$;
- $a \neq b,\;b = c,\; \implies a \neq c$;
- $a \neq b,\;b \neq c,\; a = c;\;\;$ or
- $a \neq b,\; b\neq c,\;a \neq c$.

Show that whatever the pairwise relationship between $a, b, c,\;$ it follows that:

$$\large d(a, c) \leq d(a, b) + d(b,c)\tag{triangle inequality}$$

I.e., To prove the triangle inequality holds, prove that it holds for in each of the above cases.